# How to achieve pixel perfect curves with Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, interface-design

Coming from a mobile development background, I have recently decided to learn how to design for mobile apps. I am not yet decided which tool I should use. I don't hold much knowledge in Illustrator and Photoshop - but am trying to create a screen design using Photoshop.

I was under the impression that version CS6 supported vectors and I could create pixel perfect shapes. As you can see below, one the left hand side is a rectangle in Illustrator and a circle in Photoshop. I am trying to achieve the Illustrator end result in Photoshop.

Is this possible?

I am basically trying to do is a design of a button with that end result.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Just for clarity, you *are* aware of the difference between vector and raster images? You should take a screenshot of the Illustrator curve and enlarge it as much as the Photoshop one.

Comment: I believe I am not. Time to do some more reading.

Comment: Oh, by the way. both images are zoomed in by 600%

Comment: Zooming in on a vector image redraws the *original* vectors at a larger scale. That's why I suggested a screenshot.

Comment: At 100% both images look good. It is when I zoom in that I can see the pixels...
My concern with this is that when I export this image to Android, it will lose quality in devices with very high resolution. There are devices now with 2k resolution.

Comment: No, on a same size screen but with a higher resolution you would not *lose* quality (and you'll gain nothing either). You'd only lose quality on a screen with a *lower* resolution.

Comment: But if my image was made for a 1280x768 resolution and it is displayed in a 2K screen, then the quality of the image is lost, isnt it? But anyway, still trying to achieve same results from Illustrator in PS :)

Comment: Not really, quality is not lost, the image is just smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure even if you zoom in that close to a vector curve you are going to see those jagged edges.  Like the above comment mentioned check out the difference between raster and vector.

Comment: Hi GrooveChampion, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Now, my question is: why, at 600%, I can see the pixels in PS, but not in Illustrator? The zoom is the same... shapes are the same as well.

Comment: Try turning on `View > Pixel Preview`. Without that on, Illustrator will always render all vector artwork at the maximum resolution your monitor can handle.